# Regular expression A(B+C*) == AB + A(C*)

Tags: regex

I know that with the rule of left distributivity this regular expression:
A ( B + C )

Can be written like this:
AB + AC

My question is next. Can the rule of left distributivity be used in this example:
A ( B + C* )

So that I can get:
AB + A(C*)

Or do I get something like this:
AB + AC*

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. You don't mean "regular expression" in the Perl-et-al pattern-matching sense? And what exactly do you mean by `C*` here?

Comment: @Rup: He does. The question is asking about a theoretical aspect of regular expressions.

Comment: Aren't `AB + AC*` and `AB + A(C*)` the same thing? Or is the first one parsed as `AB + (AC)*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AB + A(C*)` is definitely correct (and `AB + AC*` is almost certainly also correct, depending on the precedence of `*`).

The regex in question is `A ( B + C* )` ⇔ `A ( B + (C*) )`. If we use `c` = `C*` as a subsitution, we can write the original regex as `A ( B + c )`, now it is obvious that we can use the rule of left-distributivity. Doing all the steps in one go:

```
A ( B + C* ) <=> A ( B + (C*) ) <=> AB + A(C*) <=> AB + AC*
```

(There is more working than necessary here, for didactic purposes, and I'm using `<=>` to mean "is equivalent to".)

We can also just look at what the regex in question match (it's not a proof, but it's a good demonstration that they are equivalent):

- `A(B + C*)` matches `A` followed by either a single `B` or any number of `C`s. e.g. `AB`, `A`, `AC`, `ACC`, `ACCC` ...
- `AB + A(C*)` matches either `AB` or `A` followed by any number of `C`s. e.g. `AB`, `A`, `AC`, `ACC`, `ACCC` ...

And those are exactly the same thing.

Comment: @dbaupp thanks for your help. Do you know any website that has rules for regular expressions (theory rules). Thanks

Comment: @depecheSoul, The Wikipedia article on regular expressions has a section on [the formal theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory). And I just saw [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140287/transformation-of-a-regular-expression) recently which lists a whole pile of transformation rules (i.e. regular expression equivalences). I can't offer anything else sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `A(B+C*)` is not the same as `AB + A(C*)`.
The fist expression matches strings like ABBBBBBBBBBBBB or ABBBBBBBBBBBC
The second expression matches strings like ABBBBBBBBBBBA or ABBBBBBBBBBBACCCCCCCCCCC

Comment: This is a theoretical regex question so the `+` means alternation (i.e. `|`) rather than one-or-more.

Comment: Yeah, that's what confused me. I don't think `+` here means plus in the usual regular expression match-one-or-more sense, nor the brackets. I can see how you could make a regular expression distributed law out of the `|` or operator though.

Answer (score 0):

AB + A(C*) this one is correct because

C* means 0 or more(u have 0 or multiple of C there)
C+ means 1 or more(at least one c or more than one )

Comment: `C+` doesn't mean 1 or more, the `+` means alternation. If `+` did mean one or more, this answer would be incorrect as `AB+A(C*)` is not equivalent to `A(B+C*)` (see [@MarcoS's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10428996/1256624)), in fact, if `+` was one-or-more, the rule of left-distributivity wouldn't hold.